# How To Search in Database Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I did my search on Stackoverflow but I didn't find the solution I'm looking for

I want to search in database firebase if The "Name" is equal to The name in Navigation Title and also the "Email" that user use to signIn is equal to The Email in Database then it will avoid user to add new item

The Json looks like this

```
"Items" : {
      "-KUMSKLFqMjclbqygnPL" : {
      "Item" : "asdfg"
      "Name" : "Fadi”,
      "User Email" : "i@i.com"
      }
    }
```

My code is

```
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    var NAME : String!
    var UserEmail : String!
    var email : String!

    databaseRef.child("Items").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with:  { snapshot in

        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        NAME = (snapshotValue?["Name"] as? String)!

         UserEmail = (snapshotValue?["User Email"] as? String)!
      email = (FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.email)!

       if NAME == navigationItem.title {

            if UserEmail == email {
                print ("you can't add new item \(UserEmail)")
            }else if UserEmail != email {
                print("you can add new Item")

            }
       }
    })
```

My problem is If there is name equal Fadi but there are two different emails 
The result will be

```
you can't add new item Optional("i@i.com")
you can add new Item
```

It should print only

```
you can't add new item Optional("i@i.com")
```

I don't know how to Break it , Right now it's looks like it looping through all database

**Updated** :

I try the Dravidian answer

Result of print(snapShot.value) :

```
    "-KUMS7J-rCglHrVGX840" =     {
    "Item" = "asdsd"            
    "Name" = "a";
    "User Email" = "a@a.com";
    };
```

The result is right! but now I need to extract User Email from that node

Comment: You already have indicated you are using Swift by using the `swift` tag. No need to add that to the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for finding the node which has a specific name try this:-

```
  let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
  databaseRef.child("Items").queryOrdered(byChild: "Name").queryEqual(toValue: "Fadi").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapShot) in

        if let snapDict = snapShot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

              for each in snapDict{
                      let key  = each.key as! String
                      let name = each.value["Name"] as! String
                      print(key)
                      print(name)
                 }
            }
        }, withCancel: {(Err) in

            print(Err.localizedDescription)

    })
```

Comment: fadi is just a random name , 
I will explain it again
There is a table ,its cells are a,b,c,d,f,g
and there are many users 
user1 have email i@i.com
user2 have email a@a.com
user3 have email s@s.com
When user1 signing in he can add item for any cells a to g , but he can add item once for every cells 
that mean if he add item in cell a 
and then try to add item again to cell a it will display error message . 
when user2 signing in he can add to every cells for one time and so on like user1 
so everything depended on both the cell name and the user email
to avoid user add many time!

Comment: @Basil that is quite extensive , i have given you a basic idea of how to query to DB with a key, Happy Coding :)

Comment: Just to be sure i explaining extensive =) , Anyway Thank you  , Have a nice day =)

Comment: This will give me a whole node , how can I extract information from the node ?

Comment: I try it and got error : [FirebaseDatabase] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Name" at /Items to your security rules for better performance
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Thank you so much , You Are AWESOME , Thank you again =)